How to prove that this binary optimization problem can be decomposed into two subproblems?
I am an engineer who is currently working with some network placement problem and currently I am running into a strange situation.
My original optimization problem has the following form:
\begin{array}{ll}
\min & a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
\text{s.t.} & a_2 + a_3 \ge 1 \\
& b_1 + b_2 \ge 1 \\
& a_i, b_i \in \{0, 1\}
\end{array}
At first glance, it seems to be some sort of set cover problem. I try to decompose this problem into 2 smaller subproblems (they are still binary integer optimization) just by intuition.
Subproblem 1
\begin{array}{ll}
\min & a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \\
\text{s.t.} & a_2 + a_3 \ge 1
\end{array}
Subproblem 2
\begin{array}{ll}
\min & b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
\text{s.t.} & b_1 + b_2 \ge 1
\end{array}
It seems to me that I can solve these subproblems and combine their solutions and this solution will match the solution of the original bigger problem. I think that this is possible because the objective function and the constraint are loosely coupled.
Is it possible to actually construct a rigorous proof to show that

It is possible to decompose the original problem into two subproblems?

Combining the feasible solution of the two subproblems will lead us to the feasible solution of the original problem?


Would you kindly help me with this?
Thank you for your enthusiasm!

The problem is oddly formulated.    Since $a_1, b_3$ do not appear in the constraints....why not just set them to $0$?  And then what's left over is obviously minimized at $2$, right?

Also, I don't understand the meaning of $a_i, b_i\in {0,1}$.  Do you mean that each variable can only take the values $0$ and $1$?  If that's the case, then it's just a finite problem, and not a big one.  So even if there are other constraints you forgot to mention, you can just try all possible values.

Hello lulu this is a small instance of the set cover problem you can just do an exhaustive search however this problem is actually Np complete

As I say, this problem is trivially solved by inspection.  Sure, you might be thinking of a broad class of problems of which this is just one straight forward example, but it's hard to guess what class of problems you have in mind.  I think you'd be better off taking an example which illustrated the formidable problems the broader class might encounter.

Consider optimization problem $(1)$:
$$\min_{x,y} f(x) + g(y)$$
subject to $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.

Consider optimization problem $(2)$:
$$\min_x f(x)$$ subject to $x \in X$.
and optimization problem $(3)$:
$$\min_y g(y)$$ subject to $y\in Y$.

Let's first address the second doubt:
Claim $(2)$: $(x,y)$ being feasible in optimization $(1)$ if and only if $x$ is feasible in optimization problem $(2)$ and optimization problem $(3)$.
Explanation: This is due to definition of cartesian product. I.e. $(x,y)\in X \times Y \iff x \in X \land y \in Y$.

Now, let's address the first doubt:
If $x^*$ is optimal in optimization problem $(2)$ and $y^*$ is optimal in optimization problem $(3)$, we claim that $(x^*,y^*)$ is optimal in optimization problem $(1)$. Suppose not, then we have another solution $(x_2, y_2) \in X \times Y$ such that $f(x_2)+g(y_2) < f(x^*)+g(y^*)$. However, we know that $f(x_2)\ge f(x^*)$ and $g(y_2) \ge g(y^*)$ which leaves to $f(x_2)+g(y_2) \ge f(x^*)+g(y^*)$ which is a contradiction.
Conversely, if $(x^*,y^*)$ is an optimal solution for optimization problem $(1)$, we claim that $x^*$ is an optimal solution for optimization problem $(2)$ and $y^*$ is an optimal solution for optimization problem $(3)$. Clearly, $x^*$ and $y^*$ is feasible for the corresponding optimization problem. Suppose $x^*$ is not optimal for optimization problem $(2)$, then we can find another $x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_2) < f(x^*)$. We can check then check that $(x_2, y^*)$ is feasible for optimization problem $(1)$ and we have $f(x_2)+g(y^*) < f(x^*)+g(y^*)$ which violates the optimality of $(x^*,y^*)$. The same conclusion can be reached if $y^*$ is not optimal for optimization problem $(3)$.
This type of optimization problem is separable. Note that being binary is not required for the proof.
For your problem $X=Y=\{0,1\}^3$.

Well in this case it is both $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ since f equal to g

sure, they need not be equal in general though.

I am sorry but as an engineer I am really afraid of math so does that means that both claim are true ?

yes, they are true.

Thank you I have already upvoted your answer but may I ask where can I learn the proof technique to become as proficient as you ?

Two folds: First, learn basic proof techniques such as logic and what is contradiction, contrapositive and so on. After that, read more texts about optimization where theorems and proofs are presented. Some directly just read optimization text and that is fine :)

So you used proof by contrapositive for claim 2 and direct proof for claim 1 right ?

yes, claim $1$ (feasibility) is just using definition of Cartesian product. Claim $2$ is by contradiction and by definition of optimality.

Oh thank you so it is proof by contratiction and not proof by contrapositive

Would you kindly explain this part for me, I feel a bit lost.
"We can then check that $(x_2,y^*)$" is feasible for optimization problem (1)"
How can I check that this claim is true ?

We just have to verify that $x_2 \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

if $(x_2,y^)$ is a feasible point for problem (1) then I think the objective function evaluate at $(x_2,y^)$  will become the upper bound the objective function evaluate at $(x^,y^)$.
So I think it should be $({x_2}) + g({y^}) \ge f({x^}) + g({y^})$ instead of $f({x_2}) + g({y^}) < f({x^}) + g({y^})$

Let's avoid long comments thread, I have opened a chat room here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153375/how-to-prove-that-this-binary-optimization-problem-can-be-decomposed-into-two-sub
